# Building shared libraries with eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, shared-libraries, gcc-warning

I am trying to build a dynamic library but i'm getting this error , can anyone tell me what this means ?

```
16:42:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project 5exe ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\Users\\Dylan Galea\\workspace\\5\\Debug\\" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o 5exe.o "..\\5exe.c" 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

16:42:59 Build Finished (took 120ms)
```

Comment: What kind of project is it configured for? The command line looks weird. It looks like you have messed with compiler settings.

Comment: What iv'e did was that I put the header file and the implementation of some functions into a source file in the shared library file .. and then I edited the settings for the paths through eclipse

Comment: There is no source files in your project. This is what gcc is telling you.

Comment: but msut the source files be in the shared library or in the executable file ?

Comment: What? The sources should be in you project. Then they are compiled into either library or the executable.

Comment: yes they are in the project of the shared library .. I cannot figure out what is the problem